# My relative URL path to my View breaks on Deployment

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a very standard ASP MVC app that I use a little javascript to show a Partial View.  In order to make that Javascript work I needed to hard code a path to the Partial which is different between Dev and Production.

Mainly, in Dev there is no App specification where as in Production there is.  See here:

Production=`var URL = '/WetWashRequest/wetWashRequests/GetDetails?WONumber=' + wo;`

Dev = `var URL = '/wetWashRequests/GetDetails?WONumber=' + wo;`

What this means is that as I work on it locally I delete the first part and when I want to deploy I have to remember to re add it.

This seems so ridiculously flawed that I can only assume I am being ignorant and doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `UrlHelper` to get the URLs, as long as you do it in view:

```
var URL = '@Url.Action("GetDetails")';
```

Obviously, it doesn't make sense to put all your JavaScript in view, so what I will normal do is set just this in my view, in a namespace var, and then reference it in my external JavaScript:

**View**

```
<script>
    var MyApplication = MyApplication || {};
    MyApplication.GetDetailsUrl = '@Url.Action("GetDetails")';
</script>
```

**External JS**

```
$.get(MyApplication.GetDetailsUrl, { WONumber: wo }, function (result) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for reference I did need to change `WONumber = wo` to `WONumber : wo`